# How to adjust combo boxes within footer?

Tags: html

I have a JS Fiddle here with multiple combo boxes, but for some reason my column is to the far right when I do not want it to be. See the JS Fiddle for details and context.  I am using this within an Esri ArcGIS JavaScript API application. [Here is my Fiddle](https://i.stack.imgur.com/m0kSj.png)

```
 <tr>
                    <td><select id="Select1" dojotype="dijit.form.ComboBox" autocomplete="true" hasdownarrow="true"  style="width: 175px; background-color:Black; font:black;color: white;  onchange="ValidateMFBIBULKYDOMAIN"></td>

                    <td><select id="Select2" dojotype="dijit.form.ComboBox" autocomplete="true" hasdownarrow="true"  style="width: 175px; background-color:Black; font:black;color: white;  onchange="ValidateMFBIBULKYDOMAIN"></td>

                    <td><select id="Select3" dojotype="dijit.form.ComboBox" autocomplete="true" hasdownarrow="true"  style="width: 175px; background-color:Black; font:black;color: white;  onchange="ValidateMFBIBULKYDOMAIN"></td>


                    <td><select id="Select4" dojotype="dijit.form.ComboBox" autocomplete="true" hasdownarrow="true"  style="width: 175px; background-color:Black; font:black;color: white;  onchange="ValidateMFBIBULKYDOMAIN"></td>


                    <td><select id="Select5" dojotype="dijit.form.ComboBox" autocomplete="true" hasdownarrow="true"  style="width: 175px; background-color:Black; font:black;color: white;  onchange="ValidateMFBIBULKYDOMAIN"></td>
                    </tr>


                    <tr>
                    <td><select id="Select6" dojotype="dijit.form.ComboBox" autocomplete="true" hasdownarrow="true"  style="width: 175px; background-color:Black; font:black;color: white;  onchange="ValidateMFBIBULKYDOMAIN"></td>

                    <td><select id="Select7" dojotype="dijit.form.ComboBox" autocomplete="true" hasdownarrow="true"  style="width: 175px; background-color:Black; font:black;color: white;  onchange="ValidateMFBIBULKYDOMAIN"></td>


                    <td><select id="Select8" dojotype="dijit.form.ComboBox" autocomplete="true" hasdownarrow="true"  style="width: 175px; background-color:Black; font:black;color: white;  onchange="ValidateMFBIBULKYDOMAIN"></td>



                    <td><select id="Select9" dojotype="dijit.form.ComboBox" autocomplete="true" hasdownarrow="true"  style="width: 175px; background-color:Black; font:black;color: white;  onchange="ValidateMFBIBULKYDOMAIN"></td>


                    <td><select id="Select10" dojotype="dijit.form.ComboBox" autocomplete="true" hasdownarrow="true"  style="width: 175px; background-color:Black; font:black;color: white;  onchange="ValidateMFBIBULKYDOMAIN"></td>
                    </tr>






                    <tr>
                    <td><select id="cbMFBIBULKYDOMAIN" dojotype="dijit.form.ComboBox" autocomplete="true" hasdownarrow="true"  style="width: 175px; background-color:Black; font:black;color: white;  onchange="ValidateMFBIBULKYDOMAIN"></td>
                     <td><select id="cbMFEWASTE" dojotype="dijit.form.ComboBox" autocomplete="true" hasdownarrow="true"  style="width: 175px; background-color:Black; font:black;color: white; onchange="ValidateMFEWASTE"></td>
                     <td><select id="cbWhiteGoodsBulky" dojotype="dijit.form.ComboBox" autocomplete="true" hasdownarrow="true"  style="width: 175px; background-color:Black; font:black;color: white;   onchange="ValidateWhiteGoodsBulky"></td>
                     <td><select id="cbWhiteGoods" dojotype="dijit.form.ComboBox" autocomplete="true" hasdownarrow="true"  style="width: 175px; background-color:Black; font:black;color: white; onchange="ValidateWhiteGoods"></td>
                     <td><select id="cbEwasteSubType" dojotype="dijit.form.ComboBox" autocomplete="true" hasdownarrow="true"  style="width: 175px; background-color:Black; font:black;color: white;  onchange="ValidateEWASTEMFBIDOMAIN"></td>
                     <td><select id="cbDacDomain" dojotype="dijit.form.ComboBox" autocomplete="true" hasdownarrow="true"  style="width: 175px; background-color:Black; font:black;color: white; onchange="ValidateDACDOMAIN"></td>
                    </tr>













              <tr>


                    <td><select id="cbMFBIBULKYDOMAIN1" dojotype="dijit.form.ComboBox" autocomplete="true" hasdownarrow="true"  style="width: 175px; background-color:Black; font:black;color: white;  onchange="ValidateMFIBULKYDOMAIN"></td>
                     <td><select id="cbMFEWASTE1" dojotype="dijit.form.ComboBox" autocomplete="true" hasdownarrow="true"  style="width: 175px; background-color:Black; font:black;color: white; onchange="ValidateMFEWASTE"></td>
                     <td><select id="cbWhiteGoodsBulky1" dojotype="dijit.form.ComboBox" autocomplete="true" hasdownarrow="true"  style="width: 175px; background-color:Black; font:black;color: white;   onchange="ValidateWhiteGoodsBulky1"></td>
                     <td><select id="cbWhiteGoods1" dojotype="dijit.form.ComboBox" autocomplete="true" hasdownarrow="true"  style="width: 175px; background-color:Black; font:black;color: white; onchange="ValidateWhiteGoods"></td>
                     <td><select id="cbEwasteSubType1" dojotype="dijit.form.ComboBox" autocomplete="true" hasdownarrow="true"  style="width: 175px; background-color:Black; font:black;color: white;  onchange="ValidateEWASTEMFBIDOMAIN"></td>
                     <td><select id="cbDacDomain1" dojotype="dijit.form.ComboBox" autocomplete="true" hasdownarrow="true"  style="width: 175px; background-color:Black; font:black;color: white; onchange="ValidateDACDOMAIN"></td>
                    </tr>






                    <tr>
                    <td><select id="cbMFBIBULKYDOMAIN2" dojotype="dijit.form.ComboBox" autocomplete="true" hasdownarrow="true"  style="width: 175px; background-color:Black; font:black;color: white;      onchange="ValidateMFIBULKYDOMAIN"></td>                                
                     <td><select id="cbMFEWASTE2" dojotype="dijit.form.ComboBox" autocomplete="true" hasdownarrow="true"  style="width: 175px; background-color:Black; font:black;color: white;       onchange="ValidateMFEWASTE"></td>                        
                     <td><select id="cbWhiteGoodsBulky2" dojotype="dijit.form.ComboBox" autocomplete="true" hasdownarrow="true"  style="width: 175px; background-color:Black; font:black;color: white;      onchange="ValidateWhiteGoodsBulky2"></td>                    
                     <td><select id="cbWhiteGoods2" dojotype="dijit.form.ComboBox" autocomplete="true" hasdownarrow="true"  style="width: 175px; background-color:Black; font:black;color: white;      onchange="ValidateWhiteGoods"></td>                                       
                     <td><select id="cbEwasteSubType2" dojotype="dijit.form.ComboBox" autocomplete="true" hasdownarrow="true"  style="width: 175px; background-color:Black; font:black;color: white;       onchange="ValidateEWASTEMFBIDOMAIN"></td>                                                               
                     <td><select id="cbDacDomain2" dojotype="dijit.form.ComboBox" autocomplete="true" hasdownarrow="true"  style="width: 175px; background-color:Black; font:black;color: white;       onchange="ValidateDACDOMAIN"></td>                                                   
                    </tr>
```

[image: first ten combo boxes are appended to the initial sets, where I would like to maintain the same architecture as the others, with 10 per column...]

Comment: What are you trying or want to do?

Answer (score 1):

It's impossible to answer without getting more information, but it sounds like you don't want the first 10 boxes to be stacked up, but to be horizontal like the remaining rows.

If this is indeed the problem, then there is a mistake in your table, which places each `<td>` under a single `<tr>` which, by the nature of HTML tables, will cause then to stack.

For example, for the first 10 boxes you have this:

```
<tr>
  <td></td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td></td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td></td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td></td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td></td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td></td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td></td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td></td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td></td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td></td>
</tr>
```

when instead you need this:

```
<tr>
  <td></td>
  <td></td>
  <td></td>
  <td></td>
  <td></td>
  <td></td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td></td>
  <td></td>
  <td></td>
  <td></td>
  <td></td>
  <td></td>
</tr>
```